# Using (nautilus) Files 3.20.4 from Ubuntu 17.04 to access a second hard drive (sdb)

Tags: nautilus

Using Files (Nautilus) 3.20.4 from Ubuntu 17.04 to access a second hard drive (/dev/sdb) detaches the Files application current instance from Unity UI. Am I the only one to observe this (bug)?

Note: The Ubuntu is installed in a VM using VirtualBox.

Comment: In fact, I just realize that the (sdb) instance get attached to the "hard drive" (Unity) icon (instead of the regular "File Cabinet" icon...) and it switches from one another as your browser the file system.

Answer (score 0):

On older versions of Ubuntu (not sure which ones), you had drives show up on the left panel of Nautilus. In this version you mentioned those icons are moved to 'Other Locations' tab, including options for adding network drives, devices and ftp servers.